# how to remove chrome developer tools weird line numbers

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

my developer tools has weird line numbers next to it, and i am not able to edit the content. this is only for a few websites, but i tried to inspect google.com and it wasn't there. i tried a few other sites and it wasn't there, only for a few. i am trying really hard to remove this, but i have no idea how. please tell me how. i tried doing a few things, but it did not work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHlSx.png

the above image is a screenshot of the problem i am having. any help is appreciated